# How to merge two form fields with JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

I have register form in Joomla with few duplicate fields.
What i want to do is merge two form fields "First name" and "Last name" into 3rd field "Name" with space between them..

I'm using this code to duplicate password field and it works for one field.
but i'm not able to merge the 2 fields..

```
jQuery(function() { 
jQuery("#password_field").change(function() { 
jQuery('#password2_field').val(this.value);});
});
```

Is there any way how merge 2fields into 3rd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#FirstName,#LastName").on('keyup',function(){
  var firstName = $('#FirstName').val();
  var lastName = $('#LastName').val();
  $('#mergeName').val(`${firstName} ${lastName}`);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<form action="">
  First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" class="autoMerge" id="FirstName"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" class="autoMerge" id="LastName" ><br>
  Merged: <input type="text" name="mergeName" id="mergeName"><br>
</form> 

</body>
```

Hi you can use something like this.

Comment: This is a nice solution. But if you use on `input` instead of on `change` event, your taget (merged) field will get updated automatically while you type instead of losing focus

Comment: hi. thanks. as im using this in joomla form im not able to edit classes of the fields and as i see you using common class "autoMerge".. i can get all fields only with individual IDs

Comment: Can you use id's ?

Comment: yes.. i can get all 3 fields only with different ids..

Comment: ok i am modifying code you can check in i while

Comment: you can check it now.

Answer (score 0):

try to do something like this:

```
var firstName= document.getElementById('firstName').value;
var lastName= document.getElementById('lastName').value;
var mergeName= firstName + " " + lastName;
document.getElementById('mergeName').innerHTML= mergeName;
```

Comment: hi.. i try this add to my site but it seems its not working.. i changed ids for mine, but maybe i have to add something else?? you can see it here after you put some product do cart - https://2.svet-vciel.sk/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=cart 2 source fields are after email